# How to automate webpage button control using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to automate webpage button control like having `span` child by using

`driver. findElement_by_xpath ()`

on `Ubuntu` Linux and `chromium Autotest`

The wesite is:  https://www.youtube.com/my_webcam?privacy=public

I would like to click on Start recording button. 
`HTML` source is:

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-dark yt-uix-button-has-icon webcam-record-button" type="button" onclick=";return false;" id="record-button">
<span class="yt-uix-button-icon-wrapper">
<span class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-upload yt-sprite">
</span>
</span>
<span class="yt-uix-button-content">Start recording </span>
</button>
```

We have tried  it by using

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector() 
driver.find_element_by_id()
driver.find_element_by_xpath ()
```

However, nothing has worked. Could you please suggest us appropriate solution?

Comment: What selectors have you tried?  What errors or exceptions have occurred?

Comment: Thank you for reply . Tried selectors like :   #elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#record-button').click()
           #elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.yt-uix-button-content').click()
           #elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-dark yt-uix-button-has-icon webcam-record-button').click()
           elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('webcam-record-state').click()

Comment: #elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#record-button.yt-uix-button.yt-uix-button-size-default.yt-uix-button-dark.yt-uix-button-has-icon.webcam-record-button').click()            
#record_xpath = '//*[@id="record-button"]/span[1]/span'
           #record_xpath = '//*[@id="record-button"]/span[2]'
           #elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(record_xpath).click()
           #elm = driver.find_element_by_id('record-button').click()                                               Exceptions have occurred:  NoSuchElementException Message: u'no such element\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record button is within an iframe, you'll need to switch that iframe first and then locate the button with your chosen selector.

```
iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#webcam-container")
self.driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
record = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#record-button > span.yt-uix-button-content")
record.click()
```

Comment: Thank you Mark.  But seems that Chrome driver python does not support .switchTo()  so its throwing exception as "driver.switchTo().frame(iframe)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'  "  Could you please suggest any appropriate solution.

Comment: I just realised I used the Java method, rather than the python `switch_to_frame()`, edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.   It has worked with slitly changes. as sugested by Mark Rowlands   like  self.driver.switch_to_frame(Frame1)